# Is it guaranteed, that read-modify-write operation reads (and returns) a correct old value on weak memory models?

Tags: c++, caching, arm, memory-barriers, stdatomic

Let's say, I have a following code, that utilizes RMW operations, and is executed on WMM CPU (for example, on ARM):

```cpp
std::atomic<int> shared;

std::atomic<bool> t0_is_last;
std::atomic<bool> t1_is_last;

void t0() {
    int result0 = shared.fetch_or(1 << 0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    if (result == (1 << 1)) { 
        t0_is_last.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed); 
    }
}

void t1() {
    int result1 = shared.fetch_or(1 << 1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    if (result == (1 << 0)) { 
        t1_is_last.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
}
```

Here, two threads `t0` and `t1` try to `fetch_or` the same variable with relaxed memory ordering. And if one of the threads sees, that it's the last thread to succeed `fetch_or` operation, then it stores `true` with relaxed memory ordering to it's flag, that says, that the following thread was last to `fetch_or` variable `shared` (flags `t0_is_last` and `t1_is_last`).

So, is it true, that exactly one thread (not zero or both threads) gets to modify its `tX_is_last` varialbe?
In other words: is it true, that after `t0` and `t1` finish, the following holds: `t0 ^ t1`?

Or also in other words: *is it true, that the value returned by read-modify-write is present in the system* **exactly** *before the write operation (exactly the value that was modified)*?

Comment: Atomic is still atomic. Yes, it's guaranteed.

Comment: @273K I'm afraid, that if barriers are not used, then it might happen so that both `t0` and `t1` read `0`, atomically update memory location (so it becomes `(0 bit_or 1 bit_or 2) = 3`), and both t0 and t1 will end up not storing anything to `t0_is_last` and `t1_is_last`, because both t0 and t1 couldn't observe that one of them was last,  because both `result0` and `result1` ended up being `0`

Comment: How can t1 and t2 both read 0?

Comment: @273K ARM reads don't have acquire semantics, as well as writes don't have release semantics. So I'm asking, whether it's possible for RMW operations to work the following way on weak memory models, or C++11 RMW operations are mapped to the hardware the way so that cache-line is: locked before being modified -> copied (guess a barrier is needed here) -> modified -> unlocked -> copy of locked cacheline is returned (so that RMW operations are somewhat serializable??)?

Comment: You confuse memory access ordering around an atomic operation and an atomic operation.

Comment: @273K So, you want to say, that atomic RMW operations are serialized in hardware?

Comment: @273K example is in the question body

Comment: What is `result`?

Comment: @273K line 7 and line 14

Comment: They don't define `result`.

Comment: ARMv8 (including 32-bit mode) has `ldar` and `stlr` acquire loads and release stores if you want them.  But those aren't relevant for atomicity of RMW operations.  Same as on x86: `or [mem], eax` isn't an atomic RMW even though the load side has acquire semantics and the store side has release; you need `lock or [mem], eax`.  (Actually x86 needs a `lock cmpxchg` retry loop to implement `fetch_or` when the return value is used.  If you were only testing the same bit you were setting, a compiler could possibly use `lock bts`.)

Comment: Anyway, see [Is incrementing an int effectively atomic in specific cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850) re: how what CPUs have to do to make an atomic RMW atomic wrt. other cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The processor architecture doesn't matter.

When you write C++ code, then you are writing against C++'s memory model, not that of the architecture you are compiling for. It is the responsibility of the compiler to translate the C++ code's semantics in the C++ memory model to the appropriate instructions with regards to the architecture's memory model so that the observable behavior is identical to what C++ requires on its abstract machine.

C++'s memory model guarantees that there is for each atomic object a single total order of all modifications. A RMW operation such as `fetch_or` is guaranteed to return the value immediately preceding the modification done by the operation in this modification order. See [[atomics.order]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/atomics.order#10).

So, assuming you intended `shared` to be initialized to `0` (which you are currently forgetting, beware that default-construction doesn't initialize atomics before C++20), then either the first thread's `fetch_or` comes first in the modification order, storing `1`, and the second thread's `fetch_or` therefore must read `1` or the second thread comes first, storing `2`, and the first thread's `fetch_or` reads `2`.

In either case the first `fetch_or` will return `0`.

So yes, exactly one of the `tX_is_last` stores will happen (assuming there aren't any further modifications of `shared` in the program).

Also note that none of this has anything to do with memory ordering. It is completely irrelevant what memory ordering you choose. Memory ordering only affects how access to *other* objects than the atomic object are ordered (including *other* atomic objects).

Comment: *beware that default-construction doesn't initialize atomics before C++20* - In case anyone's wondering, it will work the same *in practice* on real compilers in C++17 and earlier, because global vars (static storage class) are zero-initialized.  A lock-free `atomic<bool>`'s object-representation is just a `bool` on normal implementations.  But if a Deathstation 9000 compiler really tried, it could define an `atomic<bool>` (lock-free or not) in a way that broke your program in C++17 with UB or a non-zero value (e.g. perhaps atomic<bool> inverts the object representation vs. bool.)